# copy constructor in java

Tags: java, copy-constructor, optional-parameters

```
class Client{
private String name;
private int age;
private int amount;
public Client(Client otherClient){
    name=otherClient.name;
    age=otherClient.age;
    amount=otherClient.amount;
    }
}
```

What if I want to use this later on:

```
Client c1=new Client("Smith");
```

or

```
Client c1=new Client("Smith",20);
```

or

```
Client c1=new Client("Smith",20,100);
```

How can I have optional parameters? Do I have to define constructors for each case?
Thanks

Comment: Java does not have optional parameters, you will have to define each constructor with the appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First answer is absolutely correct, but if you really want to have only one constructor for all these cases, you can write something like this:

```
public Client(String name, Integer age, Integer amount) {
    this.name = name;

    if (age != null) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    if (amount != null) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Client c1 = new Client("Smith", null, null);
Client c2 = new Client("Smith", 20, null);
Client c3 = new Client("Smith", null, 100);
Client c4 = new Client(null, 20, 100);
Client c5 = new Client("Smith", 20, 100);
```

Pay attention that I used wrapper class `Integer` instead of `int` in constructor arguments because variable of `int` type can't be `null`.

---

Also, if you make your setters return `this`, you'll simulate kind of named arguments in Java:

```
new Client().setName("Smith").setAge(20).setAmount(100)
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you have to `overload` the constructor, which is something you should read up on. It allows you to provide multiple input parameters for a method. The compiler will choose the appropriate method when the method is called.

Here are the Javadocs on overloading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: @user1347096 No problem. if you have no more questions, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark under my score. Or you can ask more questions above. Thanks